Trying to create a facial landmarking detector however i keep running into the same error
im trying to create a facial landmarking detector using OpenCV and Mediapipe however i keep running into the same error:
" ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'".
I'm running this within jupyter notebook and using python 3.9.1rc1 (since i was told mediapipe and opencv dont work past 3.10.) and using windows 10.
The tutorial i'm following installs mediapipe within the same folder I'm running Jupyter notebook which i have done using the "pip install mediapipe" command within the terminal however i'm still unsure where i'm going wrong.
The code i'm using is as follows:
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()

    if not success:
        break

    cv2.imshow("my video capture", image)

    if cv2.waitKey(100) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have reinstalled mediapipe as well as check my python version to see if it is compatible which ive seen should be compatible since its before v3.10.
I have also checked that openCV is installed in the folder im running jupyter notebook and the command line came back saying it has already been installed.

did you ever pip install opencv-python or any of its sibling packages? -- know about all your installed pythons, all involved virtual environments, all virtual machines, and on which computer your code actually runs. -- "I was told"... that is wrong for multiple reasons.

I only did the pip install opencv-python within the folder i'm running jupyter notebook. I also did this mediapipe and only installed it within the folder im running jupyter in.

and did you restart the jupyter notebook/server?

"I have also checked that openCV is installed in the folder im running jupyter notebook and the command line came back saying it has already been installed." Listen to Christoph. For example, in regards to what I quoted at the start of this comment, that isn't how Jupyter kernels typically work. The kernel usually is running off in an environment different than the one you'd get by checking on the command line after you cd'd into that directory. You need to install to that environment or connect it other ways. The magic install command(s) can often get you past such hurdles, see my comment..

 here. The magic pip install variation that you run inside the notebooks insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel backing the active notebook is running. Specifically, it would be %pip install mediapipe run in a new cell in your notebook. Try that and then restart the kernel and then try import mediapipe as mp.  Similar with %pip install opencv-python although that can do more and so you may need to restart everything.

Another consideration is that since this needs to interact potentially with hardware on your machine, pip alone may not be enough. It isn't able to do as much as a more capable environment/package manager like Anaconda/conda. But then you have a new issue in that you should learn to use Anaconda/conda properly. So for now pip may be enough but keep in mind for later in your endeavors that you may want to use more capable environment/package management. Maybe by that time though, uv will be the way to go.
